# PHP: происходит ли запрос к серверу в каждом новом блоке <?php?

Tags: php, html

PHP: происходит ли запрос к серверу в каждом новом блоке `<?php` ?

В качестве примера к ответу данный вопрос, пожалуйста, скажите, сколько запросов к серверу осуществляется в приведённом ниже коде (предполагается, что этот код находится в одном файле).

```
<?php
    require_once '<...>/data.php';
    // получаем значения переменных тем или иными способом
    $name = <...>; 
    $position = <...>; 
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Имя</td>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Должность</td>
        <td><?php echo $position; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: В даной ситуацию нужно читать что такое интерпритатор и как он работает. Для наглядности можно поставить Xdebug и посмотреть за каждым шагом

Comment: Не только в данной ситуации. В любой теме можно ответить - " нужно читать что такое ... и как оно работает". Но ТС и другие участники ожидают развёрнутый,  аргументированный ответ. Если вы упомянули Xdebug то привидите пример.

Comment: Вопрос про то как работает PHP, то есть как работает интерпритатор. Xdebug как раз и есть еще одим интерпритатором за шагами которого можно смотреть и контролировать  его действия. Смотреть что он видит и понимать что и почему именно так работает. Привести пример? не понял что можно приводить? скрипт и как дебагер его будет проходить или писать здесь что такое интерпритатор? Это же бред.

Comment: не что то такое, а конктретно интерпритатор и дебагер, извините что в один ответ не вложыл знания которые пользователь должен выучить. Иногда нужно учить основательно по деталях разбирать, а не просто прочитать про какой то отдельный момент и закончить на этом. За день пользователь прочитает и поймет что и как работает, поэтому ответ полезен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы отправляете запрос(ы) `" POST, GET, PUT, etc, ... "`, по адресу, в данном случае вы отправляете 1 запрос, скорее всего `POST`. В файле идет строгое подключение `require`, определяются 2 переменные `$name` и `$position`, те самые, что пришли в запросе `POST` - то есть массив, который содержит ключи и значения, собранные вами, а далее следует вывод, хотя для решения:

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

Есть более короткое решение:

```
<?=$name?>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Особенно новый (для меня) способ вывода порадовал.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu если бы вы начали использовать шаблоны для вывода, то еще больше радовались бы.

Comment: Это едва ли. Допускаю, что это в силу малого стажа, но лично я не вижу, что мы выигрываем с того, что пишем программу замены `%name%` на нужное имя вместо того, чтобы сразу воткуть `<?=name?>`. Как в данном примере: берём из базы данных, что нам надо, и сразу вставляем куда надо, и всё в одном файле. Убедите меня в чате, что неправ.

Comment: php - это и есть шаблонизатор. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос спустя полтора года.

Вопрос мной-новичком задан так, как будто php-файл c кодом выполняется на стороне клиента. Из php-файла никаких запросов к серверу нет в принципе, потому что он и так на сервере. И после обработки клиенту возвращается уже сгенерированный html-код.